# Replace text with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace the all the text from ~ to | with regex in javascript ?

```
test.html~1455551818474|test.html
```

So far I know how to remove after |

```
\|.*$
```

I need to find out how to remove between ~ to |

Comment: Don't forget to show your attempted code

Comment: `str = str.replace(/~.*\|/g, '')`

Comment: @anubhava, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for replacement:

```
str = 'test.html~1455551818474|test.html';
str = str.replace(/~.*\|/g, '');
//=> test.htmltest.html
```

If by any chance you want pipe character in output then use:

```
str = str.replace(/~.*\|/g, '|');
//=> test.html|test.html
```

Also keep in mind `.*` is greedy and will find longest match between `~` and `|` in input in case there are multiple of these.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```js
var str = "test.html~1455551818474|test.html";
var resp = str.replace(/~/g, "|");
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: I will need to remove all the numbers in between though

Comment: Why not add that to the question? Do not forget to specify what output you need. Try `var resp = str.replace(/~\d*/g, "");` if you need `test.html|test.html`